# Java RegEx for key value pair in one or more lines

Tags: regex

```
key1 = value1
key2 =   value2
key3  =   value3
```

key value pair in one or more lines. Tried (\w+)\s{0,}=\s{0,}(("(.+?)")|(.+?)(?=\s|$))

Comment: This is discussed here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168171/regular-expression-for-parsing-name-value-pairs OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28131004/regex-to-extract-key-value-pairs-separated-by-space-with-space-in-values

Comment: Try something like find all using `(\S*)\s*=\s*(\S*)`

Comment: This works only for single input (key1 = value1) and not working for more than one input (every key = value in the separate(new) line)